# How to install PhantomJS v2 with npm

Tags: node.js, github, npm, phantomjs

I'm trying to install PhantomJS `v2.0.0` using `npm` and after trying a couple of methods I've not found a working solution...

On NPM the latest version is `1.9.16`, so I've tried the following in my `package.json`:

1. `"phantomjs": "https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/archive/2.0.0.tar.gz"`

This gives me an error because there isn't a `package.json` for this version in the github repo.

2. `"phantomjs": "2.0.0"`

This tells me there is no version with this number available.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[phantomjs-prebuilt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-prebuilt) was renamed from [phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs) and now additionally contains binaries for version 2.1+.

```
npm -g install phantomjs-prebuilt
```

The fork [phantomjs2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs2) is still available which contains version 2.0.

```
npm -g install phantomjs2
```

Keep in mind that not all platforms might be supported.

Comment: As of Sep24, it is not working (at least ubuntu  which leads to a 404 page on Github and windows which is not supported)

Comment: [phantomjs-prebuilt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-prebuilt) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Phantomjs may be installed as a brew package. Confirm this:

```
brew ls | grep phantomjs
```

If you do have phantomjs installed as a brew package, you can easily uninstall it:

```
brew uninstall phantomjs
```

Then try rerunning `npm install` after updating your package.json for "2.0.0".

FYI: Please read semantic versioning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/3412545

Answer (score 2):

I had troubles to install it via npm.

I decided to build it. **I'm running Ubuntu 15.10**.

First, check you have all the development packages installed :

`sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ flex bison gperf ruby perl libsqlite3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libicu-dev libfreetype6 libssl-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev python libx11-dev libxext-dev`

Then download the source code : https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.0.0-source.zip

And run :
`cd phantomjs-2.0.0-source
sudo ./build.sh`

**It's a very long process to build it !** Be sure you know what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

**npm install phantomjs-prebuilt** try this for node users